# flyway db2 create procedure

Tags: db2, flyway

I am using `flyway commandline 2.0.3` to migrate a db2 LUW database. It works fine for various scripts holding create table statements etc. But I am not able to execute a create procedure statement. The begin-end block seems to be handled wrong.

```
SET CURRENT SCHEMA = DB2INST1;

SET CURRENT PATH = SYSIBM,SYSFUN,SYSPROC,SYSIBMADM,DB2INST1;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ${schema_name_node}.SP_E_H_A_D_V (
    IN "@M" VARCHAR(15000),
    IN "@S" TIMESTAMP,
    IN "@E" TIMESTAMP,
    IN "@T" DECIMAL(4, 2) )
  SPECIFIC "SP_E_H_A_D_V"
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
  LANGUAGE SQL
  NOT DETERMINISTIC
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION
  READS SQL DATA
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT
  INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS
  OLD SAVEPOINT LEVEL
BEGIN 
DECLARE V_MINUTES INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
...
```

Here is the output for the migrate-command:

```
 D:\flyway-commandline-2.0.3-dist\flyway-commandline-2.0.3>flyway.cmd migrate
Flyway (Command-line Tool) v.2.0.3

Current schema version: 1.13.1.201211151200.04.000
Migrating to version 1.13.1.201212101200.04.000
ERROR: com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Error executing statement
 at line 5: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE JUDITH_NODE.SP_E_H_A_D_V
 (
    IN "@M"     VARCHAR(15000),
    IN "@S"     TIMESTAMP,
    IN "@E"     TIMESTAMP,
    IN "@T"     DECIMAL(4, 2) )
  SPECIFIC "SP_E_H_A_D_V"
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
  LANGUAGE SQL
  NOT DETERMINISTIC
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION
  READS SQL DATA
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT
  INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS
  OLD SAVEPOINT LEVEL
BEGIN
DECLARE V_MINUTES INTEGER DEFAULT 0
ERROR: Caused by com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ro: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42
601, SQLERRMC=END-OF-STATEMENT;ES INTEGER DEFAULT 0;<psm_semicolon>, DRIVER=3.58
.82
ERROR: FlywayException: Migration to version 1.13.1.201212101200.04.000 failed!
Changes successfully rolled back.
ERROR: Occured in com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.DbMigrator.applyMigration
() at line 266
```

I found a question to a similar problem with `hsql` and `flyway 1.7`.

Is there a way to handle the problem for db2-database?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported yet. Please file an enhancement request in the [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/list). Make sure to include a script containing a CREATE PROCEDURE statement so I can make sure your case is covered by tests.

Answer (score 1):

We've been able to get past most BEGIN/END block issues with DB2 flyway scripts by using a trick of adding a comment immediately after the semicolon for statements inside the block.

```
BEGIN
  Statment1;--
  Statment2;--
  Statment3;--
END;
```

This works when applying scripts using DB2 CLP as well as JDBC.